# How to show triple-state, double-action column via Material icons?

Tags: material-design, actions

I have this boolean field that can be null too. So I have three states: null, true, false.

Based on it, I have two actions: make true, make false

Is there a good UI/UX way to combine all of them in one understandable UI element?

Right now I have this design. If a field is null, it's showed as false. If field is false, it's showed as a cancel material icon. If it's true, it's showed as a check icon. On hover, if it's false or null, `click to approve` would be shown, and in case it's true `click to disapprove` would be shown.:

[image]

These are the problems I have with this design:

- Clickability of items is not apparent. Thous users with my system soon realize it, since I have consistency
- Null items need to be shown differently, and they can't be shown empty, since empty won't be clickable.

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use something similar to the [indeterminate checkbox](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/checkbox), from Google Material, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

For the null state you could use a minus signal.

Answer (score 1):

How about an icon with one side for true, other side for false, middle for null. If you want to make it true, you click on the true side, false click on the false side.

Comment: Genius. You mean a tertiary toggle. That's fabulous. Do you have ideas on how to implement it?